# Syncing a shared file in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, synchronization

While sharing a file/folder with another Dropbox user, will that file/folder appear in the other user's Dropbox and sync automatically to the Dropbox folder on his computer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If that user has set the shared file/folder to sync to their computer then yes, it will stay updated when their dropbox syncs.

Keep in mind, though, that there are many ways that the file/folder could be out of sync:

- Other person hasn't turned on their computer
- Other person hasn't turned on syncing for that file/folder
- Other person has `Dropbox` setup to *not* auto-sync
- Other person has that file open and `Dropbox` can't update the file because it's in use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
As long as both the users are connected to the internet, it would work.
The sync may not occur if automatically synchronization is disabled on any of the computers.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that you have shared the folder - not a "share link" but rather share folder.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is this correct information?